# Does the effect of the Command spell take place immediately if cast on the target's turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, reactions

> The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or follow the command **on its next turn.**

If you were to cast Command as a reaction (e.g. readied action or war caster opportunity) on the turn of the spell's target, does the effect of the spell take place immediately or on the next round?

e.g. If I held the command spell and triggered it once an orc ran around the corner into view and told it to "grovel", would that end the orc's turn there, or would the orc complete it's turn unaffected, only being forced to grovel next round?

> Grovel: The target falls prone and then ends its turn.

Comment: This question has already been asked an answered [here.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103984/when-does-an-on-their-next-turn-spell-cast-as-a-reaction-take-effect)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I had done a search and saw that question before I made my own, but I only read through about two thirds of the answer. (It doesn't answer the actual question I needed until the very end of it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ )

Comment: No worries at all, you didn't do anything wrong! Having a duplicate question is not an issue and actually helps other people find the answer by providing other wordings to search for! Oh, and welcome to the site. Good first question. :)